# Assign variable to another variable name

Tags: lua, logic, coronasdk

How can I assign variable to another variable name? for example, I would like to achieve the following

```
        function ballPosition(ballType)
            balls[ball].ballType.x  = balls[ball].x
            balls[ball].ballType.y  = balls[ball].y
        end

    if balls[ball].type == "fireBall" then
        ballPosition(fireBall)
    elseif balls[ball].type == "powerLessBall" then
        ballPosition(powerLessBall)
    end
```

at the moment i have:

```
        if balls[ball].type == "fireBall" then
            balls[ball].fireBall.x  = balls[ball].x
            balls[ball].fireBall.y  = balls[ball].y
        elseif balls[ball].type == "powerLessBall" then
            balls[ball].powerLessBall.x = balls[ball].x
            balls[ball].powerLessBall.y     = balls[ball].y
        end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`balls[ball][balls[ball].type].x = balls[ball].x`

or more clearly

```
balltype = balls[ball].type
balls[ball][balltype].x = balls[ball].x
```